# Multiple custom broadcasting (how to handle)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to add a custom broadcast receiver to my app. and I have 3 methods that should do the broadcast. and in my onReceive method i want to identify which method did the broadcast. I have 3 methods like this

```
public void method01(View v){
    int flag = 1;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addFlags(flag);
    broadcastIntent(intent);
}

public void method02(){
    int flag = 2;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addFlags(flag);
    broadcastIntent(intent);    
}

public void method03(){
    int flag = 3;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addFlags(flag);
    broadcastIntent(intent);
}
```

and this is my broadcastIntent method

```
public void broadcastIntent(Intent intent){
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

in my onReceive method i use getFlags() method to get the flag value from the intent and send it through a if, else. but this do not work. any suggestion for improvements are welcome.

Comment: Did you omit intent target from your snippets (like specifying a component/action)? In other words, are you able to receive intents in your receiver at all? It isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.. No, I'm not receiving it from my receiver at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the way to this and thought of sharing the code. this is the broadcasting done in my main activity for 2 different methods.

```
public void method1(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("method1");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

public void method2(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("method2");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

and this is how i receive it..

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast Intent Detected.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

this  is how i registered it on manifest.

```
 <receiver android:name="Receiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="method1" >
            </action>
            <action android:name="method2" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Hope this will help if any one else came up with similar problem. and big thank you to every one who posted their answers here.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that ypu didn't specify a target for your intent. You can use intent filters and actions like rodkarom suggested or specify receiver's class directly (see in my example). In both cases you need either to declare your broadcast receiver in [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html), or register it at runtime (see rodkarom's answer for a sample).

The method `addFlags` is used to specify some internal properties of Intent (like start activity corresponding to this intent in a new task) , so you cannot use it for your own data. The list of possible flags is in the documentation for [setFlags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29) method.

You can use [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to achieve your goal:

```
// an Activity is just an example
public class SenderActivity extends Activity {

    // ...        
    void method01() {
        int flag = 1;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Receiver.class); // any Context is acceptable here
        intent.putExtra(MyReceiver.EXTRA_FLAG, flag); // any string will do well, you just need it to be the same here and in getExtra later
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}


public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
    public static final String EXTRA_FLAG = "your.package.name.EXTRA_FLAG";

    // and in onReceive
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        int flag = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_FLAG, someDefaultValue);
        if (flag == 1) {
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer, In onReceive method they show error under EXTRA_FLAG, I tried using intent.EXTRA also, but no success. (i have onReceive() and broadcasting methods in different activities, so  EXTRA_FLAG cannot be resolved i think)

Comment: just call intent.putExtra( "intValue" , 1) before sending broadcast and call intent.getIntExtra in your receiver

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Actions to identify each one of you Intent objects.

```
String action1 = "first_sender";
String action2 = "second_sender";

Intent createIntent01(){
Intent intent01 = new Intent();
intent01.setAction(action1);
return intent01;
}
Intent createIntent02(){
Intent intent02 = new Intent();
intent01.setAction(action2);
return intent02;
}
```

And in your `onReceive` method you can use the `getAction()` method of intents to check which action was sent. This is in case you're not already using Actions.

**[[EDIT]]**

To register a `BroadcastReceiver` you need to define an `IntentFilter` and register the actions you wish to receive this way:

```
mBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new mBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(action1);
intentFilter.addAction(action2);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);

class mBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1){
    String action = arg1.getAction();
    if(action.equals(action1)){
        //do something
    }else if(action.equals(action2)){
       //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @rodkarom Thanks for the answer, if you have any source, can provide me a detailed version of this.